# Ошибка авторизации SSH по ключам

Tags: php, ssh, клиент-сервер

При попытке подключиться выдает: `Ошибка: Не удалось соединиться с сервером!`.

```
public function connect($hostname) {
    if($link = ssh2_connect($hostname, 22)) {
        if(ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($link, 'usertest', '/home/usertest/.ssh/id_rsa.pub', '/home/usertest/.ssh/id_rsa')) {
            return $link;
        }
    }
    exit("Ошибка: Не удалось соединиться с сервером!");
}
```

Через [putty](http://www.putty.org/) подключается успешно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Видимо, $hostname неверный.

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу вывод команды: `$ file /home/usertest/.ssh/id_rsa*; head -n 1 /home/usertest/.ssh/id_rsa*`